# How to save JSON to PHP and then insert it to a database?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm struggling to send JSON to PHP script so I could insert it's data to a database.
I created a website with 3 PHP files. First is a login form and it only contains html form with post method:

login.php

```
<form method="post" action="verify.php">
    Login:<input type="text" name="user" maxlength="20" size="20"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="20" size="20"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

verify.php checks if the logged person exists in a database, starts a PHP session and then it redirects to session.php - main site which is supposed to display browser info and put it in a database:

```
<BODY>
    <?php
    $user = htmlentities ($_POST['user'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $pass = htmlentities ($_POST['pass'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $link = mysqli_connect('myServer', 'myName', 'myPass', 'myDB');

    if(!$link) {
        echo "Error: ". mysqli_connect_errno()." ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
    $record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $id_user = $record['id'];
    
    if(!$record)
    {
        mysqli_close($link);
        echo "User does not exist!";
    }
    else
    {
        if($record['password']==$pass)
        {
            session_start();
            
            mysqli_close($link);
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            $_SESSION['id_user'] = $id_user;

            header('Location: sesja.php');

        }
        else
        {
            mysqli_close($link);
            echo "Wrong password!";
        }
    }
    ?>
</BODY>
```

sesssion.php executes JS script to create a JSON containing information about browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let browserName = (function (agent) {
        switch (true) {
            case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1: return "MS Edge";
            case agent.indexOf("edg/") > -1: return "Edge (chromium based)";
            case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr: return "Opera";
            case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome: return "Chrome";
            case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1: return "MS IE";
            case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1: return "Mozilla Firefox";
            case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1: return "Safari";
            default: return "other";
        }
    })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    let browserResolution = window.screen.width + "x" + window.screen.height;
    let browserWindow = window.innerWidth + "x" + window.innerHeight;
    let browserColorDepth = window.screen.colorDepth;
    let browserCookies = navigator.cookieEnabled;
    let browserJava = navigator.javaEnabled();
    let browserLanguage = navigator.language;

    let browserInfo = {
        "browserName": browserName,
        "browserResolution": browserResolution,
        "browserWindow": browserWindow,
        "browserColorDepth": browserColorDepth,
        "browserCookies": browserCookies,
        "browserJava": browserJava,
        "browserLanguage": browserLanguage
    };

    let browserJson = JSON.stringify(browserInfo);
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("browserInfo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "session.php");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(browserJson);

</script>
```

session.php

```
<div id="browserInfo">
        <?php
            if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
            {
                header('Location: login.php');
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                $link = mysqli_connect("<SERVER CONNECTION>");

                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $username = $_SESSION['user'];
                $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
                $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

                $browser_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
                echo $browser_json;

                $user = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

                $rekord = mysqli_fetch_array($user);
                if(($rekord) && ($rekord['password']==$pass)){
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, "<MY INSERT SQL>");
                    if(!$result){
                        echo "Insert error! ". mysqli_connect_errno()." ".mysqli_connect_error();
                    }
                }
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

I always get the insert error. I know it's because JS is executed later than PHP (client side and server side). How can I edit this script to obtain JSON in PHP and then insert it to DB?

I tried inserting JSON into PHP session variables, but it didn't work. I want do do it properly.
I am also trying to use AJAX, but I don't really uderstand how it works.

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `htmlentities` to try and "escape" SQL. Throw that code in the trash. It's an extremely damaging anti-pattern and a habit you need to curb immediately.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: _but I don't really uderstand how it works_ is a bit of a problem. I suggest you do some reading so you do understand how this works before trying it. This code has numerous problems. What is sesja.php? If all you want to do is to look at the user agent, you do not need to do that in JavaScript.

Comment: I understand that my code is pretty bad, however it is desired by my uni to finish this task. Unfortunatelly, I have to do this with this "pattern". I'm just wondering how can I pass JSON (from where and where to) to insert it's data to db. I know it is not safe the way it is done right now, but (it sounds bad) it doesn't have to be. I'm not a web dev, I don't even want to be. It is just another project I need to finish to pass.